# Instagram blocking images

Tags: javascript, python, flask

I have a very simple Python/Flask/HTML page running and I am trying to display the user's most popular image.

I added a simple img tag: `<img src="{{post}}" alt="HTML5 Icon" style="width:300px;height:300px;">`

My back-end for flask:

```
from instaloader import Instaloader, Profile

def func(): 
   ....
   user=request.form['username']
   post=getPost(user) #internal function to get me the most popular post
   return render_template('posts.html', post=post.url)
```

However, my image is just not loading. When I click on the link (i.e. open the link in my browser), it works perfectly.

---

I looked over past posts and I tried implementing what they suggested.
What I tried:

1. I tried adding a `crossorigin` element to my `img` HTML tag and set it to "anonymous"
2. I tried base encoding my URL as suggested by a similar StackOverflow Post. This involved adjusting my `<img>` tag to: `<img crossorigin="anonymous" src="data:image/jpg;base64,{{post}}" alt="HTML5 Icon" style="width:300px;height:300px;">` and my back-end flask app would look like:

```
x=post.url.encode('utf-8')
temp= base64.b64encode(x).decode('utf-8')
return render_template('posts.html', post=temp)
```

Whatever I try doesn't seem to work. Is there a simple solution to this? Why is instagram blocking the image from being displayed?

Answer (score 0):

if you are use urls in your project to show image, you must noticed that urls from instagram (or Facebook) have some period which you can use, then you need to update urls

Comment: Yes but the image doesn't even appear the first time when I receive them. Idk why something so simple is turning out to be so hard. I was thinking my other alternative would be to use an instagram iframe and maybe that will work.